# IOS7 UIAlertView not called - (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated

Tags: ios7, uialertview

I subclass the UIAlertView, and Overide the function

```
[- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

On IOS6, it's called when I press on Ok button;
but On IOS7 ,it's not worked;

Why is it not working?
when I press on the Ok button,I want to check the input on `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]` whether the input is true; if it is not true, the alertView not dismiss and I will add a shaking animation on the alertView;
How can I realize this effect?

thank you

I override the function like this:

```
// Override to customise when alert is dimsissed
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (_shakingDelegate && [_shakingDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:canDismissWithClickedButtonIndex:)]) {
        BOOL canDismiss = YES;
        canDismiss = [_shakingDelegate alertView:self canDismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
        if (canDismiss) {
            [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
        }
    }
}
```

It is not called when I press on the button in IOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't subclass UIALertView in IOS 7

because I think layout is now changed in IOS 7 (I didn't try it)

Make your own view as alertview ... Hope it helps

Comment: thanks,I have to custom the alertView to avoid resolve the diff between IOS7 and IOS6.